# How to swipe between fragment in android studio using kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

i am making an app containing 12 fragment , and that are loaded according to current month(for 0 fragment One loaded in app lunch). But after loading, it needs to slide left and right.

This is mainactivity.kt

```
package office.kidslab.basicgeometry

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        when (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            0 -> {
                val fragment = One()
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.contaner, fragment)
                transaction.commit()
            }

            1 -> {
                val fragment = Two()
                val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                transaction.replace(R.id.contaner, fragment)
                transaction.commit()
            }
...

        }
    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#313131">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contaner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using ViewPager2. It handles all the swiping gesture for you. See https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419